# How to show popup window on validation event?

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-3, validation, data-annotations

It looks like I'm stuck trying to find a good solution for my issue. We have an MVC 3 application and a form, which we validate using Data Annotations. On Email field I have a RemoteAttribute which checks, that Email is unque.
The this I need to implement:

1. If Email is unique - everything is ok, we don' tneed to do anything.
2. If Email is not unque - we need to show a modal popup window with a yes\no choice. If user 
   chooses "yes" - the field will be valid, if "no" - field is invalid and we need to show a popup message.

Unfortunatelly, I couldn't find any good solution for this

Small update: I don't want to validate the whole form: only the Email field. In this case, can't really understand how to use form.Validate from jQuery or ValidationSummary

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

In your view create container for errors form ModelState:

```
<div id="errorPopUp" style="display:none">
    @Html.ValidationSummary()
</div>
```

and in script section of your view:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    if(@:!ModelState.IsValid) {
            $('#errorPopUp').dialog({
                resizable: false,
                width: 400,
                modal: true,
                autoOpen: true
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use jquery validate to do this:

```
            var frm = $('#formData');

            frm.validate();
            if (frm.valid()) {
            // do nth or submit the form
            }
            else{
                 // Declare a dialog
                 var $dialog = $('#dialogdiv').dialog({
                     autoOpen: false,
                     modal: true
                 });
                 // Declare the yes/no options
                 ....
           }
```

Is this the thing you need?

Hope this help :)

Comment: looks, like it's my backdoor. I was thinking about this way of validation, but wanted to find out smth with data annotations

Comment: you can still specify your rule with data annotations, and use this to validate :)

Comment: but when should I call frm.validate()? When I loose the focus on the field? How can I use this validation with data annotations?